# How to hold US dollars as a citizen but non resident

Tags: united-states, bank-account

Say if I were to remotely work for an American company, I'd be paid in dollars. To have a place to keep those dollars I'd need a American bank account, but for that I have to have a permanent address which I don't have.

I want to hold money in dollars to invest in the american stock market and also as currency in where I live is devaluing.

How am I to proceed? I only have an account in the country I currently live in

Comment: Why can't you receive USD payments in your country of residence? And if you live outside the US - why do you need USD necessarily, wouldn't local currency be better?

Comment: Talk to an international bank that can handle accounts in multiple currencies. Open a USD account. Solved?

Comment: Use your parents address?  Sibling or other relative’s address?  That’s what i’d suggest if one of my children want to work overseas.  My grandparents were always my uncle’s “official”address, no matter where he lived.

Comment: @RonJohn Are you sure this is legal?

Comment: @Philipp why not?  Whole companies have been formed around providing "wanderers" with a stable address, and **these are your family** (the place you'd reasonably go when you return before finding a new place to live).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most consumer banks offer foreign currency accounts. That's a separate bank account that maintains its balance in a foreign currency and can be used to receive and make international payments in that currency without conversion fees and without any risks due to currency fluctuations. Unless, of course, your country of residence is under banking sanctions by the US government. In that case it might be very difficult for you to receive *any* payments in US$. Also, banks tend to charge higher service fees for foreign currency accounts. And if you want to transfer money into your usual bank account in local currency, you will of course have to pay conversion fees.

Ask your local banks for their offers regarding foreign currency accounts.